# Show integrability of convex (and increasing) function of martingale (submartingale)

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

[image]

I want to prove the above lemma. How can I show (c)? There is a hint: for $f:I\to \mathbb R$ convex and increasing, there exist $a \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb R_+$ such that $a+bx\leq f(x)$. I showed that the hint is correct, but how can I apply it in this context?

Comment: I am wondering whether there is a simpler proof than that was proposed by John Dawkins...

Answer (score 0):

The negative part $Y_t^-$ of $Y_t$ is integrable because $f$ is bounded below by an affine function, per the hint. Meanwhile, by Jensen, if $0\le  s<t$, then $E[Y_t^+|\mathcal F_s]\ge f(E[M_t|\mathcal F_s])^+=f(M_s)^+=Y_s^+$ (the positive part of $Y_s$), even on $\{E[Y_t|\mathcal F_s]=+\infty\}$. Consequently, $E[Y^+_t]\ge E[Y_s^+]$, so the integrability of $Y_t$ implies that of $Y_s$ for $0\le s<t$.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by what you are saying. To show (c), we want to assume the integrability of $Y_t$ and then show that $Y_s$ is integrable for all $s\in T$ with $s\le T$. So if we assume that $Y_t$ is integrable, then $Y_t^-$ is integrable by assumption.

Comment: $Y_t^-$ is *necessarily* integrable because $f$ is convex and $M_t$ is integrable. So the integrability of $Y_t$ is equivalent to the integrability of $Y^+_t$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins So we have that $Y_t^{-}\geq a+bM_t^{-}$ for some $a,b$ and because $M_t^{-}$ is integrable (because $(M_t)_{t \in T}$ is a martingale) we know that $Y_t^{-}$ is integrable. Right?

And by $f(E[M_t|\mathcal F_s])^+$ you mean $\bigg(f(E[M_t|\mathcal F_s])\bigg)^+$, right?

Comment: Yes, in both instances.